# Sort categories list by counting item

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

For example, I have 5 categories in Woocommerce like

> A(3) ( 3 for the items in category A )
>
> B(7)
>
> C(22)
>
> D(1)
>
> E(0)

They are display in category page and ordered by something like id.

And I want rearrange the results to be display in categories list page that sort from higher to lower, like

> C(22)
>
> B(7)
>
> A(3)
>
> D(1)
>
> E(0)

Is there any solution with using the hook `pre_get_posts` ( or other hook ) to fix this issue?

I have tried to test the hook `woocommerce_before_subcategory` and it just shows me one category at a time and I cannot edit any one of them.

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is possible, see [wp_list_category](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/wp_list_categories)

```
<?php wp_list_category('orderby=count'); ?>
```

Comment: Thank you, but `wp_list_categories` won't change the result of categroy page.

Answer (score 1):

After testing the code in Woocommerce, and I found a solution with `woocommerce_product_subcategories_args` hook.

```
add_filter('woocommerce_product_subcategories_args', 'ProductSubcategoryArguments', 999, 1);

function ProductSubcategoryArguments($arg=array()){
    $arg['order']='DESC';
    $arg['orderby']='count';
    return $arg;
}
```